# Trying AJAX autocheckboxes example; getting Notice: Undefined index: #ajax in ajax_form_callback()

Tags: ajax

I'm using the exact code found within the [examples module](http://drupal.org/project/examples) `function ajax_example_autocheckboxes` though I have changed the function and callback names. When I change the select dropdown the field goes gray for a second as the AJAX process kicks off; but no checkboxes appear. I don't think it matters, but my form is in a block defined in my custom module.

I'm getting this in my recent log messages:

```
Type    php
Date    Wednesday, March 21, 2012 - 12:24
User    me
Location    http://localhost.com/system/ajax
Referrer    http://localhost.com/node
Message Notice: Undefined index: #ajax in ajax_form_callback() (line 379 of C:\Users\me\Documents\www\localhost.com\includes\ajax.inc).
Severity    notice
Hostname    127.0.0.1
```

**UPDATE:** I tried the examples module (ajax examples) in a clean D7 install and get 503 errors trying to open the example pages; now I'm investigating my hosting environment (xampp) will update once resolved.

**UPDATE2:** Installed a bitnami drupal stack & tested ajax examples; everything works as expected which points to an issue with my xampp environment.

FYI xampp details:

```
    ###### ApacheFriends XAMPP version 1.7.7 ######

  + Apache 2.2.21
  + MySQL 5.5.16 (Community Server)
  + PHP 5.3.8 (VC9 X86 32bit thread safe) + PEAR
  + XAMPP Control Panel Version 2.5 from www.nat32.com 
  + (BETA) XAMPP Control Panel Version 3.0.2 by Steffen Strueber (not in the USB & lite version)
    see http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=46743
  + XAMPP Security
  + OpenSSL 1.0.0e
  + phpMyAdmin 3.4.5
  + ADOdb 5.14
  + Mercury Mail Transport System v4.62 (not in the USB & lite version)
  + FileZilla FTP Server 0.9.39 (not in the USB & lite version)
  + Webalizer 2.23-04 (not in the USB & lite version)
  + Perl 5.10.1 (not in the USB & lite version)
  + Mod_perl 2.0.4 (not in the USB & lite version)
  + Tomcat 7.0.21 (not in the USB & lite version)
```

Comment: Are you able to post the code you're currently using? The example module you're using works fine if memory serves so the problem is probably something to do with the function name changes

Comment: @Clive lmk if you want the block code too.

Comment: removed my code from post; see update in post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reinstall XAMPP!** if that doesn't fix it, try a different stack:

- [Bitnami](http://bitnami.org/stacks)
- [Acquia](http://www.acquia.com/downloads)
- [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info)

So installing the Bitnami Drupal stack and testing successfully there indicated a problem with my XAMPP install. Also wanted to try the Acquia stack, was ok, ended up going back to XAMPP.